# Reuse last line on terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

When one issues a command that does not exist in the terminal, it results in:

The program 'programname' is not installed. You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install programname
```

Is there any shortcut by which one does not have to retype the 'sudo apt-get install programname' line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is none by default, but it is not so hard to define one:

```
alias ii='sudo apt-get install'
```

You can then just call

```
ii !!
```

For more information, read `man bash` on aliases and history.

Comment: of course, the package isn't _always_ called `programname` ...

Comment: @Useless: well, then you have to use the mouse, or `screen` and its copy mode...

Answer (score 6):

Since the **suggested command** was not typed before, it won't be in the bash history. So <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or `.bash_history` will not help.

setting an alias for `sudo apt-get install` will reduce some typing but you still need to type the name of the program, particularly if the *programname* is differnt from the *package-name*.

The simplest way to "type" the command without typing is to copy the line from the terminal and paste it.

- To copy the line, highlight `sudo apt-get install programname` using the mouse and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
- To paste, make sure the cursor is at the `$` prompt and  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Hope this help.

Comment: you can usually copy by just selecting, and paste by just clicking the middle mouse button, unless the defaults changed recently

Comment: Thanks @Useless, however, I couldn't copy by selection alone on my laptop. And it has no middle mouse button to test the paste.

Comment: @user68186, try pressing left and right buttons simultaneously

Comment: Thanks @vissi, I am not using a mouse. On the touchpad I can press either the left or the right.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the part you are trying to avoid is re-typing the last command, you can use the bash built-in "bang-bang" as a parameter for apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install !!
```

That will replace the "!!" with the previous command you typed.

Here's a reference about other advanced shell features:

http://www.deadman.org/bash.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just hit the <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> key on your keyboard. Hit it again to invoke the command you used before, etc.

Also, you can check out the history of your issued commands by entering:

```
gedit ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: Up-arrow does not lead to the sudo apt-get command. It leads to the previous command I typed in

Comment: I am sorry this answer wasn't helpful to you, but your title was arguably a bit ambiguous. Even though this answer might not be the one you are looking for, other users might find it helpful when searching for the use case I was referring to.